# How to fix typing error Shapes and Connectors with SymbolPalette in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, syncfusion

I try to duplicate the creation of Symbol Palette on my component, but I got errors on the types :

```
let connectorSymbols: ConnectorModel[] = [...]
```

or

```
let palettes : any
```

I have syntax error, I am a beginner on VueJS and I never encountered this kind of declaration.

Could you help me ?

I use a boilerplate vue and webpack, is that enough ?

Answer (score 0):

The following details are needed,

1. We need more information about your exact requirement and if possible provide issue reproducible sample?
2. Did you follow all the steps in the [getting-started](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/color-picker/getting-started/) documentation to create Vue ColorPicker sample using Webpack?

We have created simple Vue ColorPicker sample using webpack and it can be download from [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/224893/ze/quickstart-606330902).